# How to fix docker login error: Error saving credentials

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-desktop, ubuntu-22.04

When trying `docker login`, I get this error:

```
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: docker-credential-desktop resolves to executable in current directory (./docker-credential-desktop), out: ``
```

I run an Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS machine.

I tried purging and reinstalling docker from scratch, but didn't solve the issue.
I also tried solutions to similar "saving credentials" errors found on StackOverflow, but didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

***Solution***

In the file `~/.docker/config.json`, change `credsStore` to `credStore` (note the missing `s`).

***Explanation***

The error seems to be introduced when moving from 'docker' to 'Docker Desktop', and vice-versa.
In fact, Docker Desktop uses an entry `credsStore`, while docker installed from apt uses `credStore`.

***Extra***

This solution also seems to work for the following, similar error:

```
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exec: "docker-credential-desktop":
executable file not found in $PATH, out: ``
```

which may occur when pulling docker images from a repository.

Answer (score 0):

If this may have been caused by uninstalling Docker Desktop and installing Docker, edit the file `~/.docker/config.json` and delete the `credsStore` or `credStore` key and value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).